# Java, convert file stream to random-access file

Tags: java, file, stream, java-io

I need to implement a wrapper between 2 interfaces that I cannot do any change. Basically the wrapper needs to convert java style streaming file access to standard C style fopen/fread/fwrite/ file access (implemented in java).

The wrapper must implement random file access methods required by caller, which means open/read/write/close/seek/flush/size/truncate; The wrapper must call a set of standard java file streaming methods to feed caller, the callee provides me inputstream and outputsteam.

I saw java.io.RandomAccessFile, it converts C style to java stream style, I need something reversed. The most difficult part is seek(). Is there any good (efficient) way to do it.

Comment: May this link can help you. [http://www.coderanch.com/t/277378/Streams/java/InputStream-RandomAccessFile-best-way](http://www.coderanch.com/t/277378/Streams/java/InputStream-RandomAccessFile-best-way)

Comment: You could transfer the entire stream data into an in-memory buffer (`ByteArrayOutputStream` will automatically grow; `toByteArray` will return the underlying `byte[]`) and then you can do random access on that... but this is a hackish solution.

Comment: Pramod gave me the very first and very helpful comment. Pramod, will you create an answer instead of a comment so that I can give you credit? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get random access to a stream is to buffer it in memory (or as a copy on disk)

I would suggest either

- Reading it into a ByteArrayOutputStream and turning it into a `byte[]`
- Copying the stream to a temporary file (preferably a tmpfs or ram drive) and then use RandomAccessFile on that.

Comment: Reading into byte array is as easy as 
byte[] org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File file) ... but this won't work when file size exceeds available memory.  You can easily convert RandomAccessFile to stream with "Channels.newInputStream(randomAccessFile.getChannel());"... I will elaborate in a separate answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is easily achievable using the Channels utility class...

```
// STEP 1:  Create random access file read-only
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("/text.txt", "r");

// STEP 2:  Use Channels to convert to InputStream
InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(raf.getChannel());
```